# AC dimmer- triggering triac using moc3041. lamp always remain on, and does not change its intensity

Tags: opto-isolator, triac, dimmer

Below is schematic.

1. Problem is lamp always remains on,even if i haven't provided the Anode A terminal with power through micro controller.
2. Also please explain me the need for R7 resistor.
3. Is it because the  triac remains always triggered from AC through resistor R7.

[image: optoisolator is moc3041]

Comment: What is the block in the middle?

Comment: The lamp is on always or just want turn off?

Comment: I guess in the middle is opto-triac.

Comment: Do you want ability to turn on/off lamp (like in circuit) or you want to be able to dim the light?

Comment: the block in middle is MOC3041 opto-isolator for driving the triac gate.Pl do explain its working as i didn't found in datasheets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [MOC3041M](https://www.fairchildsemi.com/datasheets/MO/MOC3041M.pdf) contains a zero-cross detector, it will always delay switching until the live-neutral voltage is 0V, ensuring the lamp is always fully on or fully off.

To do phase-cutting dimming, you need a different optotriac, such as the [MOC3021M](http://www.futurlec.com/Datasheet/LED/MOC3010-3022.pdf) (same specs, but random-fire instead of zero-cross).

Comment: I think he wants to turn on/off only, not dimming (it would require different circuit, not just optotriac replacement). Also zero-cross type he choose have benefit of lower EMI, because it turns ON on start of phase.

Comment: @Darko His question title has "AC dimmer" in it, which is why I assumed he wanted to do dimming ;)

Comment: Yes, sorry, I see now. You are right.

Comment: If he wants dimming, than even with random-fire opto-coupler he have problem that triac turns off only when current is zero. And in this circuit he does not know when to turn on to have wanted percentage of lamp light intensity. With this circuit (+random-fire OC) it would be pretty undefined behaviour, sometimes will turn on on begin of fase, sometimes in the middle sometimes on the end... He probably expect something like with DC voltage and transistor... If he uses pwm of some relatively high frequency it would always turn on the start of the fase anyway.

Comment: thank you for help @Darko. Actually i have made another circuit for zero cross detection.Using that after a certain delay i m powering the above circuit using micro-controller GPIO.But i m not able to understand the role & working of opto-isolator apart from isolation.Pl do help.

Answer (score 1):

From the schematic, I see that you "reversed" triac T1. Either turn it over or put gate lead between R8 and opto-coupler lead MT1 (on schematic).

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fb6MZw.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

2) Need of R7 is to limit gate current of the triac.

3) Yes.

Comment: With circuit you provided (with my modification) you can only turn on/off your lamp. Not a good dimming if you want that.

Comment: Making changes as u suggested ,lamp do turn on/off  but only when gate is directly connected to battery.when powered by micro-controller  through opto-isolator it didn't work as expected.Do resistor value here play any role?

Comment: I am not sure about all details you wrote. If it works only when you connect battery to the triac (BT136), than yes. I checked the datasheet of BT136 and you need gate current to be at least 35mA to guarantee turn on in 1st and 3rd quadrants (you use those). What are the values of resistors you use?

Comment: Also when choosing resistor values take care that peek gate current allowed for this triac is 2A. This is important if you turn on at the peek of the voltage cycle (~310V for 220V AC).